# FabricJS delayed drawing?

Tags: fabricjs

I have a little demo I setup.

```
var image1 = "http://i.imgur.com/b81Wj6O.png";
var image2 = "http://i.imgur.com/vmtt98e.jpg";
var backgroundImage;
var toggle = true;

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", update);

var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas', {
  width: 800,
  height: 600
});

function update() {
    var background;
    if (toggle) {
      background = image1;
    } else {
      background = image2;
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(backgroundImage == null) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(background, function(img){
      backgroundImage = img;
      canvas.add(img);
    });
  }
  else {
    backgroundImage.setSrc(background);
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rhLa38dt/

If you click the button it should draw the an image, the issue I'm having is that when you click the button a second time the image does not update. However the 3rd time it will draw the image it should have the second time and continue from there always being 1 step behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the callback to render the canvas after setting its source:

```
backgroundImage.setSrc(background, function() {
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Updated working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/nzgf1ja4/.